# Incorrect conversion from epoch time when scraping web

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, praw

```
import praw,time
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

username=""
password=""
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='')
r.login(username,password,disable_warning=True)
posts=r.search('china disaster', subreddit=None, sort=None, syntax=None, period=None,limit=7)
title=[];created=[]
for index,post in enumerate(posts): 
    date=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(post.created))  
    title.append(post.title);created.append(post.created)
    print date,title[index]
    break #added so it prints one post as a example
```

**Error:**
I get incorrect times.

```
<time title="Fri Jan 23 01:22:20 2015 UTC" datetime="2015-01-22T17:22:20-08:00" class="">5 months ago</time>
```

I don't understand the issue, I think I making a mistake in time-zone conversion. But reddit posts mention `UTC`, thus I don't get the error.

Comment: the output does not correspond to the code. What value do you expect to get?

Comment: Added `break` statement so prints only one post as an example. Sorry for not explaining correctly before. If you mentioning about the post content, if won't as the order of top posts keep changing on reddit.

Comment: `print date` where `date` has `"%Y-%m-%d.."` format won't produce `<time title=...` output ever.

Comment: Just remove all the code unrelated to the epoch time to string conversion i.e., your input should be a single number `post.created`? ("seconds since epoch") and specify what output *exactly* do you expect and what you get instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your exact problem about how is the "Incorrect".
There are two attributes about the created time "created" and "created_utc". Maybe you want to try the second one instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. Really dumb of me to miss that.

Comment: `gmtime()` accepts "seconds since the Epoch" that should be the same number whatever timezone is i.e., if `created` is a POSIX timestamp then `created_utc` should be the same number and therefore the result won't change.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Amazing! Thanks for the explantation, makes sense now.